# How to use interface data type without attribute "KnownType" in WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontractserializer, datacontract

If I'm using "ServiceContract" that contains "OperationContract" operations.
The operation return or received interface parameters.
When I'm using the service I get an exception message:

"The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this name. Consider using a DataContractResolver if you are using DataContractSerializer or add the type corresponding to '{%className%}' to the list of known types".

I can add the attribute of KnowTypes to the interface but my interface project is separated from the implementation project and they cannot have circular dependency reference so it's not possible to declare KnowTypes.

What is the best solution?

Comment: Sounds like you need to re-design. Your interface project should not have a dependency on the implementations.

Comment: This is what I'm trying to avoid. My design have separation between the interface and it's implementation so I can't use KnownTypes attribute over the interface.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible. Similar question has already been asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192048/using-interfaces-with-wcf?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution and it's worked!

I'm using `ServiceKnownType` that load the types that implement the `ServiceKnownType` for `DataContract` members.

For example:

I have animal interface:

```
public interface IAnimal
{
    string Name { get; }

    void MakeSound();
}
```

and implementation (interface does not know the implementation types):

```
public class Cat : IAnimal
{
    public string Name =>"Kitty";

    public void MakeSound()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Meeeee-ow!");
    }
}

    public class Dog : IAnimal
    {
        public string Name => "Lucy";

        public void MakeSound()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wolf Wolf!");
        }
    }
```

For using the `Cat` and `Dog` types that implement the `IAnimal` interface in the service:

```
public interface IAnimalService: IAnimalService
{
     IAnimal GetDog();
     void InsertCat(IAnimal cat);
}
```

I can use the attribute `ServiceKnownType`that will load the type by interface type.

I Created a static class that return all the `IAnimal` types:

```
  public static class AnimalsTypeProvider
{
    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetAnimalsTypes(ICustomAttributeProvider provider)
    {
        //Get all types that implement animals. 
        //If there is more interfaces or abtract types that been used in the service can be called for each type and union result            
        IEnumerable<Type> typesThatImplementIAnimal = GetAllTypesThatImplementInterface<IAnimal>();

        return typesThatImplementIAnimal;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetAllTypesThatImplementInterface<T>()
    {
        Type interfaceType = typeof(T);
        //get all aseembly in current application
        var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
        List<Type> typeList = new List<Type>();
        //get all types from assemblies
        assemblies.ToList().ForEach(a => a.GetTypes().ToList().ForEach(t => typeList.Add(t)));

        //Get only types that implement the IAnimal interface
        var alltypesThaImplementTarget =
            typeList.Where(t => (false == t.IsAbstract) && t.IsClass && interfaceType.IsAssignableFrom(t));


        return alltypesThaImplementTarget;
    }        
}
```

and adding the class `AnnimalsTypeProvider` and method `GetAnimalsTypes` to the service interface attribute:

```
 [ServiceContract]
 [ServiceKnownType("GetAnimalsTypes", typeof(AnimalsTypeProvider))]
 public interface IServicesServer : IAnimalService
 {
     IAnimal GetDog();
     void InsertCat(IAnimal cat);
 }
```

and that's it!

It will load all the `IAnimal` known type in dynamic mode while loading the service and it will serialize the `Cat` and `Dog` without any configuration whatsoever.